# avoid SSL certificate checks using AJAX/jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, certificate-error

is there an option in AJAX/jquery get request to avoid strict ssl?

like

`--no-check-certicate` in CURL

`strictSSL : false` in (npm) request

Comment: by the way, can you tell me how you generate the SSL certificate ? I am trying it on MySQL but it is not working with me.

Comment: generate a cert? no idea :?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using option -k, --insecure in your command, it says that is sets up insecure connection, but you really shouldn't be doing that...

> -k, --insecure
>
> (TLS) By default, every SSL connection curl makes is verified to be
>   secure. This option allows curl to proceed and operate even for server
>   connections otherwise considered insecure.
>
> The server connection is verified by making sure the server's
>   certificate contains the right name and verifies successfully using
>   the cert store.
>
> See this online resource for further details: 
>   https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
>
> See also --proxy-insecure and --cacert.
>   From https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

Comment: can you add a link>

Comment: also, what about while using the fetch() API ?